# Rails ActionMailer : filter emails to a specific list in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

Without editing any of my `/app` files, I'd like to edit either `development.rb` or an initializer where I set a whitelist of testers.

Then the emails are sent only to those people in the whitelist (not to spam other users mailbox).

I though of overriding `deliver!`, or the `user.get_mail` method but :

- it's not in `/config` where it should be
- it doesn't filter gem generated emailing (ie devise, mailboxer etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [Action mailer interceptors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails)

And do something like this :

```
class BetaEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.perform_deliveries = false unless WHITELIST.include?(message.to.first)
  end
end
```

And

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(BetaEmailInterceptor)
```

This is a very naive implementation and will only work if the first recipient is whitelisted but you get the idea.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Wonderful!

Comment: Note: this does not work if the `deliver!` method is used.